# Default JSX props added through a destructured object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is this syntax correct:

```
{
   ...
   const someObj = { 
       className: 'something', 
       ref: input => this.inputRef = this,
       another: 'something'
   }

   render() { return <input { ...someObj } />; }
}
```

Or should I put those props (`className` and `ref`) directly on the input field.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it does work. You could have easily verified that by playing around with the code and the browser's inspect feature

Comment: @Prasanna: True, but that just means it works in that specific environment, with that specific version of React or the transpiler. There's value in knowing that yes, it's *supposed* to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine, if you want to do it that way. You haven't changed scopes or anything, so `this` will be okay.